# View source-code for question (even when I can't edit)

Tags: support, editing, markdown, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see how someone typeset their question in TeX.SE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/is-there-a-way-to-see-how-someone-typeset-their-question-in-tex-se)

On Wikipedia, even when I can't edit a page, I can view the source-code. Sometimes I see markup in questions (or answers) and wonder: how do I get this layout? Is there any way to view the source-code when I don't have the reputation to edit?

Comment: You should see 'improve this' or something similar under questions. That will take you to the editing screen. Do you see this?

Comment: I just check on a different browser where I am not logged in and there is a `improve this question` link, on all EXCEPT the newest question.  So perhaps the question has to been submitted for a few minutes before that link kicks in.

Comment: I don't see "improve this". Doesn't that require the privelege "edit questions and answers", which needs 2000 rep?